# Customize class loading - Java

Tags: java, class, classloader, dynamic-class-loaders

I am working in an Eclipse based RCP application, where my custom app is deployed as a plugin. I want to customize the Login window for this application, I just know the class of the original Login dialog, but do not have control to customize it.

I want to know whether custom class loading can be an option here, to tell JVM to load my custom login dialog class(which may be a subclass of the original login dialog class) instead of the original class. The application does provide login API to be used by custom applications, so that I will be able to establish the Application session once my custom login window is loaded.

Thanks in Advance. I am able to see in questions related to class loaders that people generally don't like the idea of custom class loading.

Comment: Does the plug-in that provides the original Login window provide relevant extension points?

Comment: No. It is not among published options for customization. I have to decompile the jar to know if there is any.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the customization?

Comment: want to add new features in the login dialog, like save password, auto sign-in etc. Neither the original login dialog has these, nor the Login API provide these out of the box. I am able to extend the original class, but it has many private fields so I am not able to get control of it completely. So I like my login class to be called instead of the actual login dialog class.

Comment: Have you considered submitting enhancement requests or contributing to the original project? As an observation, there may be some reluctance to go into more detail on workarounds, since they could be misused in this context.

Comment: yes. I also thought of this approach can be misused. So possibly we couldn't have a solution for this. If you add your last comment as an answer I would accept that. Thanks.

Comment: It's really more of a comment than an answer to your question. I'm good.